# Bixby : Latest Capsule Library Version

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

We got an email as Capsule Deprecation Warning (Stage 1) from the Bixby Team.

We are getting Deprecation warnings only in the library version in our capsule.

Apart from the library version we are not getting any other warning.

But as per the documentation, We have used the latest library version i.e.(1.9.24 for viv.navigation).

Link: https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/library

So, what to do for this.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reviewing your code following the Capsule Deprecation email.

We try our best to align the release of our updated libraries with Platform releases but sometimes the libraries are released (a short while) after the Stage 1 deprecation sets in, which seems to be the situation here.

We'll update this answer with a release date once we get that information.